# Как правильно переместить столбцы?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дан двумерный массив с 12 столбцами. Переставить столбики так, что-бы они были расположены так- первый - двенадцатый, второй - одиннадцатый, третий - десятый .. пятый восьмой, шестой седьмой. 
Я просто уперся рогом и не понимаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    int m;
    int index;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int array[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            array[i][j]=rand()%120;
            cout<<array[i][j]<<" "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";
}
    cout<<"\n";
    int temp=0;
////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){ 
        for (int j=0; j<m; i+=2){
            for (int k=m-1; k>j; k--) {
            if (k==m-1) temp=array[i][k];
            array[i][k]=array[i][k-1];
            if (k==j+1) array[i][k]=temp;
        }}}
////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout<<array[i][j]<<" "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: ваш код кстати рабочий, только опечатка при перемещении в цикле - вы инкрементируете `i` вместо `j`

Comment: Точно, спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @YuriyOrlov код может быть и рабочий, но Стандарту он не соответсвует.

Comment: Это всё круто, но кто-нибудь ответ напишет? @YuriyOrlov?